# Regexp_replace WITH DECIMAL is returning error ORA-01722 "Invalid Number"

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, extract, currency

In Oracle I had this code:

```
regexp_replace(DESCRIPTION_FIELD, '[^0-9.]+', '')
```

that worked fine, but now I'm getting the error:

> ORA-01722 "Invalid Number".

Removing the decimal fixes this, but removes the decimal from the returning value. I'm guessing there's some bad data added recently. Solutions?

Comment: I am not able to [reproduce your issue in this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=02f78607fa0bfc68d0bb6c9a1a2ac456). It would be good if you could show some sample data that actually generates the issue.

Comment: What is the decimal separator on your Oracle database?

Comment: It would be something like this: SELECT NVL(CAST(regexp_replace(DESCRIPTION_FIELD, '[^0-9.]+', '') AS NUMBER),0) FROM TABLE    that returns the ORA-01722 error. When I take out the decimal, it then runs fine.

Comment: Thank you for the help.   What I'm really trying to get is:   Using a text description field that can contain any data, IF it contains a floating number that CAN be a money amount, get it.    It would be nice if our description ALWAYS had a floating number, but it doesn't. There is no "$" symbol or commas, so it needs to find it by  finding numbers with a format of "Some numbers, a decimal, then two numbers". THANK YOU!

Comment: I'm not sure what our decimal separator is, sorry.  I'm a 58% expert on SQL :)

Comment: I wish I had sample data, problem is I can't find which record is causing it, and I can't provide 'bad data' that triggers this-as that IS our mystery here. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually I found one example of suspect data, something like this:
01234-1234545    54.00

Normally, our field should only have 54.00   but some have those addtional stuff, sometimes it might be XYZ2626...266.88

That should return 266.88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `regexp_replace()` isn't generating that error; the problem is when you cast the result of that replacement to a number. For example, for the original value `XYZ2626...266.88` your pattern brings back `2626...266.88`, and `to_number('2626...266.88')` throws ORA-01722.

> by finding numbers with a format of "Some numbers, a decimal, then two numbers"

You could look for that rather than trying to exclude other characters:

```
with your_table (description_field) as (
  select 'No money value' from dual
  union all
  select 'Some sensible 98765.43 value' from dual
  union all
  select '01234-1234545 54.00' from dual
  union all
  select 'XYZ2626...266.88' from dual
  union all
  select 'ABC-123.45XYZ' from dual
  union all
  select 'ABC123.45XYZ6.78' from dual
)
select description_field,
  regexp_replace(DESCRIPTION_FIELD, '[^0-9.]+', '') as original,
  regexp_replace(DESCRIPTION_FIELD, '.*?((-?\d+\.\d{2})[^0-9]*)?$', '\2') as new
from your_table;

DESCRIPTION_FIELD            ORIGINAL             NEW                 
---------------------------- -------------------- --------------------
No money value                                                        
Some sensible 98765.43 value 98765.43             98765.43            
01234-1234545 54.00          01234123454554.00    54.00               
XYZ2626...266.88             2626...266.88        266.88              
ABC-123.45XYZ                123.45               -123.45             
ABC123.45XYZ6.78             123.456.78           6.78
```

I've allowed for negative numbers but you might not want those... and if there is more than one potential money values it'll take the last one.

The capturing group `(-?\d+\.\d{2})` looks for an optional minus sign, followed by any number of digits, followed by a period, followed by exactly 2 digits. But that on its own wouldn't prevent further digits afterwards, so it's followed by `[^0-9]*` to make sure that doesn't happen. That combination is enclosed in a second grouping to allow it to be optional (followed by `?`) - otherwise values without anything that looks like a money amount are passed through unaltered, which will also error presumably.

Comment: Sir you are genius.

Comment: This solved my issue. I used your "new" expression. And that logic was on my mind, but..  that long crazy regexp is what I needed. Thank you Alex!

Comment: @IdoIT4theMoney - I realised it didn't help if there were no potential money values, and gave odd results if there was more than one; updated to hopefully be more comprehensive. (But regex isn't a string point so may well be improvable!)

Comment: Super. Thanks again. Those will help too as I do need negatives. I'm still having one more issue, if it is something like "123.78TEST1234", I want only the "123.78" portion.  I believe your regex is skipping over and trying to return 1234. (My report is erring out, since the "1234" has no decimal and the .xls can't handle it).  How can I limit this to only get the first occurance of the "123.25" formatted value? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This error would normally occur if the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS for your session has a wrong decimal point setting.

You can change the setting for your session using this:

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';
```

or

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';
```

That will set the decimal and group separator for your current sessionn only.

Or there is a more general solution in your select statement that will always assume '.' as decimal point in your data from the table. And will display the number with the decimalt point for your session.

```
select to_number(regexp_replace(ESCRIPTION_FIELD, '[^0-9.]+', ''), '999999999999.99999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''') from <your table>;
```

EDIT

If more decimal point are found in the string and you can accept that some are skipped then this might work.

```
select to_number(regexp_substr(regexp_replace(ESCRIPTION_FIELD, '[^0-9.]+', ''),'([0-9]*.[0-9]*)'), '999999999999.99999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''') from <your table>;
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. I tried altering the session both ways, still got the same error. Tried the 3rd and same error.  Ughh, I thought this would really work! I was so hopeful. (It returned the same ORA-01722 error.  We might have a few rows of data with bad bad data. Maybe at the machine level..??)

Comment: Try  "select regexp_replace(DESCRIPTION_FIELD, '[^0-9.]+', '') from <your table>" then,  that cant produce the  ORA-01722... I hope :)